# Building LLVM on Linux

Tags: iphone, c++, linux, compilation, toolchain

Well not that anyones probably going to see this but I A) figured out that LLVM wasn't what I needed it was LLVM-gcc which you can get from sauriks repo. B) realized that the toolchain I torrented already worked minus a la libstdc++ not in /usr/local/lib/gcc/arm-apple-darwin/4.0.1/ so to get libstdc++ I believe I got it from either the filesystem that comes with the torrent or my actual Ipod via SFTP. I can Proudly say that C++ can be compiled on IOS(although it was a pain in the ass :D).

not sure if linking torrents is alright on SO but for anyone that wants a link email me or pm me if you can do that on SO(i'm not sure?) the only thing I haven't tested yet is objc which I can't find any non xcode tutorials. this is what stumped me last time was finding tutorials that didn't rely on templates so heavy. I was never one for templates :D

Why keep downvoting it only hurts other users who are looking for the same answers i was?

Comment: -1: Because you accuse the devs of either poor coding or messing it on purpose, but don't take into account other possible reasons. Maybe the devs wanted to specifically aggravate  _you_ because you are  contumelious?

Comment: virtual -1: `thats just simply too much to ask of someone` <-> except for us? btw, have you tried the official mailing lists already, or is this also asked to much of you already?

Comment: well obviously if it worked I wouldn't be here YEAH i did try the mailing lists that never works because no one checks mailing lists any more I mailed saurik 3 times asking for help no answer that was 4 months ago. look all i want is to code for IOS is that so much to ask for. I love how every is so liberal with their minus -1's on here how about you just not read the damn thing if your going to be an ass about it.

Comment: oh an read into it past the words moron I came HERE because I know SO has people with the knowledge to solve this I DIDN'T come here to get harassed for every little thing I STILL  haven't hit 15 rep yet because of people like you and if I ever do I'll return the favor ten fold on you

Comment: (You could make use of more punctuation.) The point was not that I think you don't have problems, the point was that you accuse ppl with contumelious and insulting claims based on no fact (`Wow a down vote because I use linux thats cool.` -> ?!). You question the abilities of other programmers, yet you are a newbie. Get over this pubertal behaviour, and ppl are more willing to help you. Also, where is your mail? I would like to see it. If you used a style similar to the one you use here, then I wouldn't wonder too much that nobody wanted to answer. I am sure you are capable of more.

Comment: `I'll return the favor ten fold on you` -> See, this is the sort of talk I mean; you achieve basically nothing with this. At maximum, it gives me a smile, and tommorow, I won't even remember you. Realise: You are not the center of the world. Note: Stay calm, rational, and appropriate, and nobody will vote you down. I am seriously confident that you are capable of more, but not when you keep acting like this.

Comment: ahh that better explains it I think you should go back under the bridge I'm not paying any toll. I don't even care anymore it was pointless to ask for help anyway since A) if someone knew how to do it besides saurik and the dev team there would be posts on how to  fix it which there isn't and B) the majority of the toolchain would be available as a package minus the apple proprietary stuff. I am an end point guy I don't mind waiting for something but when some thing is harder than what I have the capabilty to do I drop it.

Comment: Strange that google does not find the mail. I was more interested in a link to the online archive, not for the mail text. I've found several results for LLVM and iPhone on the mailing lists, though. Have you looked at them already? Also, the more you insult, the less serious you will be taken. See, I am already talking to you like you are my son/daughter. To your bedroom now, I won't talk to you anymore unless you learned some good manners.

Comment: Your only furthering the conception that you are indeed a troll and that your abusing your mod-like status. I don't care about your Contrived theories about the way I conduct myself. Or the fact you pointed out the simple fact I dont use proper english grammar you see I'm from the south Proper english only makes you seem like a pompous ass. I dont ask for help unless its something i have no clue about if you want to help then help but dont sit here and lecture me All I wanted to do was start ios development I dont own a mac and im not shilling 800 USD for hardware to make one

Comment: One last time: a) Insults are never ever welcome here on SO. You could have insulted anyone and I would have removed it. b) I did not critique your grammar per se, but rather the length of your phrases, i.e. pls put more '.' and ',' in so they are easier to the eyes, c) It is awesome that you are trying to learn coding and I am glad that you discovered Linux as a great platform for development (I am on Linux, too), d) It is not awesome when you seriously accuse people of evil intentions without having any proof of it, but e) it's cool that you found SO; please skip insults and accusations.

Comment: Look I spent 5 LONG hours trying to fix it face it the software is broken or no longer maintained so I'm giving up because what good does a lot of broken code do. I didn't code LLVM so therefore I DON't know what happend I'm assuming apple had something to do with it. or these other guys that managed to compile it Obviously didn't get the version of the revision I had. So I don't see the point in coding for IOS when everything is broken I'm just sticking to PC development since all development for devices for OPEN software users is broken and doesn't work. Coding for devices is IMPOSSIBLE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it look alot like the usual subjects `cstdio`, `cstdlib`, `cstring` are not included.

I would start by trying including them :-)

Comment: what I do to find out what header stuff is in is check http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcmp/

Answer (score 0):

which svn revision of LLVM are you building ?

from the [page you linked](https://code.google.com/p/iphone-dev/wiki/Building):

> Currently, due to Issue 70, we are limited to revision 42498.

Comment: rev 42498 thats the one I'm building as per their word

Answer (score 0):

Read the my original Post I got it working just ported my previous PC(ie linux,win,mac) only patcher(game save) to ios :D finally :)